# Есть ли альтернативный метод "register_next_step_handler" из telebot в pyrogram-e?

Tags: python, telebot, pyrogram

Начал писать юзербота, и столкнулся с небольшой проблемой - не могу найти в документации `pyrogram` метод, который есть в библиотеке `pytelegrambotapi` (метод - `register_next_step_handler`). Вопрос - есть ли данный метод в библиотеке `pyrogram` и если есть - приведите пожалуйста пример использования.

Comment: Аналогичный вопрос. Решение нашли?

Comment: @ПавелОсипенко, к сожалению, нет(  В тот день я отказался от разработки юзерботов и больше этот вопрос не поднимал. Но если вам удастся что-то найти - был бы только рад увидеть ответ здесь:)

Answer (score 3):

В библиотеке **Pyrogram** отсутствует встроенная функциональность для обработки шагов в диалогах. Однако есть дополнительная библиотека под названием **Pyrostep**, предназначенную специально для этой цели.

Установка данной библиотеки:
`pip install pyrostep`.

Приведенный ниже код демонстрирует использование **Pyrogram** с **Pyrostep** для реализации последовательных шагов в диалоге:

```
from pyrogram import Client, filters
import pyrostep

app = Client('название_сессии')
pyrostep.listen(app)

@app.on_message(filters.command(['start']) & filters.private)
async def step1(client, message):
    await message.reply(
      "отправьте ваше имя:"
    )
    pyrostep.register_next_step(
        message.from_user.id,
        step2
    )

async def step2(client, message):
    await message.reply(
        f"Ваше имя: `{message.text}`"
    )

app.run()
```

**Pyrostep** предоставляет дополнительные функции, и более подробную информацию можно найти в репозитории **Pyrostep** по ссылке [pyrostep](https://github.com/awolverp/pyrostep).

Answer (score 0):

В фреймворке **pyrogram** данного функционала я тоже не нашел.

Посмотрел как это реализовано у других.
Если очень приближенно и если я все правильно понял, то суть в том, что при вызове метода `register_next_step_handler()` мы временно регистрируем новый хендлер, которому передаем наш текущий message из которого берется `id` чата.
И при следующем событии с данным `chat_id` (то есть отслеживаем  именно этот чат) сообщение обрабатывается именно хендлером, который потом удаляется из списка всех имеющихся хендлеров.
Как-то так. Может ошибаюсь.
Я надеюсь, что в следующих релизах **pyrogram** добавят такую возможность.

В своем же боте (на `pyrogram`), я реализовал это таким "костылем":
Сохраняю в глобальную переменную (назовем ее `wait_for_input`) значения `chat_id`, `message_id` и какой-нибудь маркер (например тот же `callback_data`), чтоб потом можно было вызвать нужную функцию (если предполагается разный отзыв на разные кнопки).
В обработчике сообщений `@bot.on_message()` в первую очередь проверяю не пуста ли эта глобальная переменная. Если не пуста и сообщение из нужного мне чата, тогда принимаю данные, делаю с ними что надо и обнуляю переменную.
Понятно, что если сообщение из другого чата, то переменная остается и будет ждать пока придет сообщение с нужного.

*Пример:*

```
from pyrogram import Client, filters
from pyrogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton

# Do not forget create config.ini file with `api_id` and `api_hash` fields.
bot = Client("stupid_bot", bot_token='')

names = list()
wait_for_input = None

button_add = InlineKeyboardButton('Добавить имя', callback_data='add')
button_remove = InlineKeyboardButton('Удалить имя', callback_data='remove')
button_show_all = InlineKeyboardButton('Посмотреть список имен', callback_data='show_all')
main_inline_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup([[button_add, button_remove], [button_show_all]])


@bot.on_message(~filters.bot)
def answer(_, message):
    global wait_for_input

    text = "Может познакомимся?"

    if wait_for_input:
        prev_chat_id, callback, = wait_for_input
        if prev_chat_id == message.chat.id:
            if callback == 'add':
                names.append(message.text)
                text = f'Привет **{message.text}**'
            else:
                try:
                    names.remove(message.text)
                    text = f'Имя **{message.text}** было удалено из списка.'
                except ValueError:
                    text = 'Нет такого имени в списке.'
            wait_for_input = None

    message.reply_text(text=text, reply_markup=main_inline_markup)


@bot.on_callback_query()
def text_handler(_, callback_query):
    global wait_for_input

    if callback_query.data == 'add':
        wait_for_input = (callback_query.message.chat.id, callback_query.data)
        callback_query.edit_message_text("Отлично, как тебя зовут?")

    elif callback_query.data == 'remove':
        wait_for_input = (callback_query.message.chat.id, callback_query.data)
        callback_query.edit_message_text("Напиши имя, которое надо удалить.")

    elif callback_query.data == 'show_all':
        callback_query.edit_message_text(
            "\n - {}".format('\n -'.join(names)) if names else 'Список пуст.',
            reply_markup=main_inline_markup
        )


bot.run()
```

В этом примере многие моменты упущены (обработка ошибок, одновременный ввод данных несколькими пользователями и многое другое).
Он написан, как говорится, "на коленке" исключительно для пояснения описанной идеи.

Comment: Как только ботом воспользуется хотя бы два человека, всё будет глючить.